# Grid.arrange forestplot objects

Tags: r, r-grid, r-forestplot

I have a couple of forest-plots made using the R package `forestplot`. I would like to `grid.arrange` them - but it seems this doesn't work easily.

Example:

```
library(forestplot)
# A basic example, create some fake data
row_names <- list(list("test = 1", expression(test >= 2)))
test_data <- data.frame(coef=c(1.59, 1.24),
                    low=c(1.4, 0.78),
                    high=c(1.8, 1.55))

forestplot(row_names,
       test_data$coef,
       test_data$low,
       test_data$high,
       zero = 1,
       cex  = 2,
       lineheight = "auto",
       xlab = "Lab axis txt")
```

Ok this will draw a plot. Now suppose I want to capture that into an object plot it side by side with another plot:

```
fp1 <- forestplot(row_names,
       test_data$coef,
       test_data$low,
       test_data$high,
       zero = 1,
       cex  = 2,
       lineheight = "auto",
       xlab = "Lab axis txt")
```

The following throws an error:

```
> grid.arrange(fp1, fp1)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Error in gList(list(path = "GRID.VP.7537", name = "arrange.1-1-1-1", n = 2L,  : 
only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

So cleary fp1 is not a grob - but how do I achieve this by other means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the second example in the help pages `?forestplot`. which shows how to do this.

---

`forestplot` doesn't seem to return the plot: look at `str(fp1)`.

A couple of options is use `grid` to create the plotting space (v1), or else capture the plot and then combine (v2).

---

v1 using grid

```
library(grid)
library(forestplot)

# Create 2 rows by one columns viewport
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(2, 1)))

# Plot in viewport position 1x1
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1))
forestplot(row_names,
       test_data$coef,
       test_data$low,
       test_data$high,
       zero = 1,
       cex  = 2,
       lineheight = "auto",
       xlab = "Lab axis txt")
upViewport(1)

# Plot in viewport position 2x1
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=2, layout.pos.col=1))
forestplot(row_names,
       test_data$coef,
       test_data$low,
       test_data$high,
       zero = 1,
       cex  = 2,
       lineheight = "auto",
       xlab = "Lab axis txt", 
       new_page = FALSE)
upViewport(1)
```

---

v2, capture the plot

```
fp1 <- grid.grabExpr(print(forestplot(row_names,
       test_data$coef,
       test_data$low,
       test_data$high,
       zero = 1,
       cex  = 2,
       lineheight = "auto",
       xlab = "Lab axis txt")))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(fp1, fp1)
```

Comment: thx user. Option v1 is giving me an error: `Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
  no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL" `. Option v2 works but in my real plots, i have labels and titles that overlap when I set `gridExtra::grid.arrange(fp1, fp2. ncols=2)`

Comment: @user2498193 ; do you get an error when you copy and paste the v1 answer in to a fresh R session? (as I can't reproduce that). Re v2 ; it is a bit more temperamental, in that you need to size your output window or device for suitable positioning.

Comment: Yeah still get the error in a fresh session. Eh re v2 - dunno how to do all that. I'm starting to think I might just do this manually

Comment: Re v1: this seems to be a local PC problem. A quick [internet search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Error+in+UseMethod(%22depth%22)+:+no+applicable+method+for+%27depth%27+applied+to+an+object+of+class+%22NULL%22) of the error you get, seems to bring up similar with ggplot / grid plots : maybe something in there to give you a hint. Re v2 I meant to resize the output device, such as,`pdf("test.pdf", width=10, hieght=10) ; gridExtra::grid.arrange(fp1, fp1) ; dev.off()` , where you change the width and  height to suit.